# Aggregation Strategy based on message size of aggregate

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to aggregate exchanges, and when then exchange hits a certain size (say 20KB) I would like to mark the exchange as closed.

I have a rudimentary implementation that checks size of the exchange and if it is 18KB I return true from my predicate.  However, if a messages comes in that is 4KB and it is currently 17KB that will mean I will complete the aggregation when it is 21KB which is too big.

Any ideas on how to solve this?  Can I do something in the aggregation strategy to reject the join and start a new Exchange to aggregate on?

I figured I could put it through another process to check actual size remove messages off the end of the message to fit the size, and for each removed message, push them back through...but that seems a little ugly because I have a constantly compensating routine that would likely execute.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an eager complete option you can use to mark it as complete when you have that 17 + 4 > 20 situation. Then it will complete the 17, and start a new group with the 4.

See the docs at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/aggregate-eip.adoc

And you would also likely need to use `PreCompleteAggregationStrategy' and return true in that 17 + 4 > 20 situation, as otherwise it would group them together first and complete, eg so it becomes 21. But by using both the eager completion check option and this interface you can do as you want.

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/PreCompletionAwareAggregationStrategy.java

Comment: Thanks Claus.  I'll take a look at that.  I must admit it has been a while since I've used Camel and I'm glad to be back using it to solve some real EIP problems.  I need to check what is new since 2.11 days.

Comment: Ok, so implemented the PreCompletion interface: `public boolean preComplete(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
   String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
   String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
   
   return (oldBody+newBody).length() > (10*2000) ? true : false ;
  }` works just with that.  If the new exchange will  make the old exchange 20k then it completes the aggregated one and creates new.  Not sure I need to use eagercomplete. The examples suggested you use that when you want to send a STOP to force aggregation to complete.